# Datatables disable individual column search for hidden column

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

i have hidden a column in my datatable. But i get problem when using individual column searching (text). i want to disable the hidden column searching, but it seems not working. The search textbox still appear.

```
oTable = $("#tracedata1").dataTable({
             "bAutoWidth" : false,
             "bRetrieve"  : true,
             "scrollY": 200,
             "scrollX": true,
             "deferRender": true,
             "scroller": {
                   loadingIndicator: true
                   },
             "serverSide" : true,
             "processing" : true,
             "sAjaxSource": 'show2ndsampl.php',
             "fnServerData": function (sSource,aoData,fnCallback){
                    $.ajax({
                             "dataType":'json',
                             "type":'POST',
                             "url":sSource,
                             "data":aoData,
                             "success":function(json){
                                   fnCallback(json);
                                   }
                             });
                    },
            "order"  : [[1,"desc"]],
            "aoColumns"  : [
                    /*ID*/{"visible":false, "searchable":false},
                   /*date*/        null
```

[image]
 Show error : `stopPropagation is not defined`

Comment: Could you please add a `snippet` or `fiddle`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have 10 columns. but i hide 2 columns. how to hide unwanted search input.

Comment: Can you recreate this problem in `fiddle` or `snippet` is what I meant..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have tried on `http://jsfiddle.net/s8F9V/510/` and it works. but it isn't in my serverside datatable